# Transform table data to XML

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I have data like this:

```
        ID DUE_DATE         KIND UNPAID_AMOUNT REQUIRED_AMOUNT PAID_AMOUNT RECEIVED   ENTERED   
---------- ---------- ---------- ------------- --------------- ----------- ---------- ----------
   9331779 2017-08-11         11                        606.42      127.59 2017-07-17 2017-07-18
   9331779 2017-08-11         11                        606.42      446.81 2017-08-16 2017-08-17
   9331779 2017-08-11         11                        606.42       32.02 2017-09-15 2017-09-18
   9331782 2017-11-11         11                        606.42       95.57 2017-11-15 2017-11-16
   9331782 2017-11-11         11                        606.42      446.81 2017-12-15 2017-12-18
   9331782 2017-11-11         11                        606.42       64.04 2018-01-03 2018-01-04
```

I want to transform this into XML data, looking like:

```
 <payment-list>
    <payment>
      <kind>11</kind>
      <due>2017-08-11</due>
      <amount>null/0</amount>
      <waiting>606.42</waiting>
      <related-payment-list>
        <related-payment>
          <received>2017-07-17</received>
          <entered>2017-07-18</entered>
          <amount>127.59</amount>
        </related-payment>
        <related-payment>
          <received>2017-08-16</received>
          <entered>2017-08-17</entered>
          <amount>446.81</amount>
        </related-payment>
       <related-payment>...
      </related-payment-list>
    </payment>
    <payment>
      <kind>11</kind>
      <due>2017-11-11</due>
      <amount>null/0</amount>
      <waiting>606.42</waiting>
      <related-payment-list>
        <related-payment>
          <received>2017-11-15</received>
          <entered>2017-11-16</entered>
          <amount>95.57</amount>
        </related-payment>
        <related-payment>
          <received>2017-12-15</received>
          <entered>2017-12-18</entered>
          <amount>446.81</amount>
        </related-payment>
       <related-payment>...
      </related-payment-list>
    </payment>
 <payment-list>
```

Can this be done in single query? I have an idea/way to do it in loop, but maybe someone has other idea, using XMLAgg etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesting `XMLAgg()` calls is a bit tricky, but you could do this in two stages; first get each ID/due/kind/amount with a list of related payments:

```
select id, due_date, kind, unpaid_amount, required_amount,
  xmlagg(xmlelement("related-payment",
    xmlforest(received as "received", entered as "entered", paid_amount as "amount")))
from your_table
group by id, due_date, kind, unpaid_amount, required_amount;
```

which with your sample data gives (with the XMl fragment serialized for readability):

```
        ID DUE_DATE         KIND UNPAID_AMOUNT REQUIRED_AMOUNT XMLSERIALIZE(CONTENTXMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("RELATED-PAYMENT",XMLFOREST(RECEIVEDAS"REC
---------- ---------- ---------- ------------- --------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   9331779 2017-08-11         11                        606.42 <related-payment>                                                               
                                                                 <received>2017-07-17</received>                                               
                                                                 <entered>2017-07-18</entered>                                                 
                                                                 <amount>127.59</amount>                                                       
                                                               </related-payment>                                                              
                                                               <related-payment>                                                               
                                                                 <received>2017-09-15</received>                                               
...
```

and then use that as an inline view for the second level of aggregation:

```
select
  xmlelement("payment-list",
    xmlagg(
      xmlelement("payment",
        xmlforest(kind as "kind",
          to_char(due_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as "due",
          nvl(unpaid_amount, 0) as "amount",
          nvl(required_amount, 0) as "waiting",
          related_payments as "related-payment-list"
        )
      )
    )
  ) as result
from (
  select id, due_date, kind, unpaid_amount, required_amount,
    xmlagg(
      xmlelement("related-payment",
        xmlforest(received as "received",
          entered as "entered",
          paid_amount as "amount"
        )
      )
    ) as related_payments
  from your_table
  group by id, due_date, kind, unpaid_amount, required_amount
);
```

Demo with your sample data as a CTE, and again adding serialization for readability:

```
-- CTE for sample data
with your_table (id, due_date, kind, unpaid_amount, required_amount, paid_amount, received, entered) as (
            select 9331779, date '2017-08-11', 11, null, 606.42, 127.59, date '2017-07-17', date '2017-07-18' from dual
  union all select 9331779, date '2017-08-11', 11, null, 606.42, 446.81, date '2017-08-16', date '2017-08-17' from dual
  union all select 9331779, date '2017-08-11', 11, null, 606.42, 32.02, date '2017-09-15', date '2017-09-18' from dual
  union all select 9331782, date '2017-11-11', 11, null, 606.42, 95.57, date '2017-11-15', date '2017-11-16' from dual
  union all select 9331782, date '2017-11-11', 11, null, 606.42, 446.81, date '2017-12-15', date '2017-12-18' from dual
  union all select 9331782, date '2017-11-11', 11, null, 606.42, 64.04, date '2018-01-03', date '2018-01-04' from dual
)
-- actual query
select xmlserialize(document
  xmlelement("payment-list",
    xmlagg(
      xmlelement("payment",
        xmlforest(kind as "kind",
          to_char(due_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as "due",
          nvl(unpaid_amount, 0) as "amount",
          nvl(required_amount, 0) as "waiting",
          related_payments as "related-payment-list"
        )
      )
    )
  )
  indent size=2) as result
from (
  select id, due_date, kind, unpaid_amount, required_amount,
    xmlagg(
      xmlelement("related-payment",
        xmlforest(received as "received",
          entered as "entered",
          paid_amount as "amount"
        )
      )
    ) as related_payments
  from your_table
  group by id, due_date, kind, unpaid_amount, required_amount
);
```

which gets:

```
RESULT                                                                          
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<payment-list>
  <payment>
    <kind>11</kind>
    <due>2017-08-11</due>
    <amount>0</amount>
    <waiting>606.42</waiting>
    <related-payment-list>
      <related-payment>
        <received>2017-07-17</received>
        <entered>2017-07-18</entered>
        <amount>127.59</amount>
      </related-payment>
      <related-payment>
        <received>2017-09-15</received>
        <entered>2017-09-18</entered>
        <amount>32.02</amount>
      </related-payment>
      <related-payment>
        <received>2017-08-16</received>
        <entered>2017-08-17</entered>
        <amount>446.81</amount>
      </related-payment>
    </related-payment-list>
  </payment>
  <payment>
    <kind>11</kind>
    <due>2017-11-11</due>
    <amount>0</amount>
    <waiting>606.42</waiting>
    <related-payment-list>
      <related-payment>
        <received>2017-11-15</received>
        <entered>2017-11-16</entered>
        <amount>95.57</amount>
      </related-payment>
      <related-payment>
        <received>2018-01-03</received>
        <entered>2018-01-04</entered>
        <amount>64.04</amount>
      </related-payment>
      <related-payment>
        <received>2017-12-15</received>
        <entered>2017-12-18</entered>
        <amount>446.81</amount>
      </related-payment>
    </related-payment-list>
  </payment>
</payment-list>
```

Comment: Smooth as... Thanks!